# Hide address bar on chrome mobile

Tags: browser, address-bar

I have spent a lot of time reading several approaches about this subject. None of the suggestions seem to work for me though.
I would like to make the adress bar of a browser under Android/iPhone etc. disappear to get a native app feeling.
At the moment I am trying to make this happen for Android (Chrome). I hoped it would be easy with the new Chrome version because it hides the bar when scrolling. But using window.scrollTo(x,y) just scrolls the page without making the address bar disappear.

I hope anybody can help me.

Comment: Where do you want to reach that? In an app?

Comment: The user accesses our website by entering our web address in the browser address bar. Our website contains JavaScript code which (hopefully) will hide the address bar.

Comment: Same Issue , Any Help in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request full screen. i'm not sure if your users wil like it.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/10/Let-Your-Content-Do-the-Talking-Fullscreen-API

Comment: This sounds interesting, but not so many browsers (especially older ones) support it. I sure will give it a thought!

Comment: I think it will - I think it *should* - give your users a warning aka 'this website is now fullscreen <exit>'.

Answer (score 0):

ios

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/Application/IpadIcon.png">
<link href="images/Application/SplashScreen.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and   (orientation: landscape)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Comment: This specifies a startup image, right?
This is not quite what I need. I would like to make the browser fullscreen when requesting our website from the server.